# Encoding URLs containing unicode characters

Tags: android-networking

Is there an Android class that (correctly) encodes URLs containing unicode characters? For example:

```
Blue Öyster Cult
```

Is converted to the following using java.net.URI:

```
uri.toString()
 (java.lang.String) Blue%20Öyster%20Cult
```

The Ö character is not encoded. Using `URLEncoder`:

```
URLEncoder.encode("Blue Öyster Cult", "UTF-8").toString()
 (java.lang.String) Blue+%C3%96yster+Cult
```

It encodes too much (i.e. spaces become "+" and path separators "/" become %2F). If I click on a link containing unicode characters with the Dolphin web browser it works correctly, so obviously this can be done. But if I try to open an HttpURLConnection using any of the above strings, I get an `HTTP 404 Not Found` exception.

Comment: [**The latter method is correct.**](http://ideone.com/bAnuL8) `%2F` is a percent-encoded `/`, which is not present in the string `"Blue Öyster Cult"`. There is a spurious disconnect between what you were testing and what you should use.

Comment: @MattBall I accidentally pasted the %2F from earlier testing (corrected). But that's also an issue. The real URL is a complete HTTP link containing slashes that I don't want encoded.

Comment: Then you need to encode the components before constructing the entire URL string. If you've got a string representing a URL with some parts that should be percent-encoded and some parts that shouldn't, it's already too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up hacking together a solution that seems to work for this, but is probably not the most robust:

```
url = new URL(userSuppliedPath);
String context = url.getProtocol();
String hostname = url.getHost();
String thePath = url.getPath();
int port = url.getPort();
thePath = thePath.replaceAll("(^/|/$)", ""); // removes beginning/end slash
String encodedPath = URLEncoder.encode(thePath, "UTF-8"); // encodes unicode characters
encodedPath = encodedPath.replace("+", "%20"); // change + to %20 (space)
encodedPath = encodedPath.replace("%2F", "/"); // change %2F back to slash
urlString = context + "://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + encodedPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

URLEncoder is designed to be used to encode form content, not whole URI's.  Encoding / as %2F is intentional to prevent user input from being interpreted as a directory, and + is valid encoding for form data.  (form data == part of the URI following the ?)

Ideally, you would encode "Blue Öyster Cult" *before* appending it to your base URI, instead of encoding the whole string.  And if "Blue Öyster Cult" is part of the path instead of part of the query string, you have to replace + with %20 yourself.  With these restrictions, URLEncoder works fine.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. There is no method that will do this cleanly. The links are parsed from HTML files and can also be user supplied. I use URL.getPath() to get the path portion but then need to encode it.